# SharePoint list event receivers not firing when copying and pasting using explorer view

Tags: sharepoint, copy-paste

Here's the deal, I have various event receivers registered to a document library:

- ItemAdded
- ItemAdding
- ItemFileMoved
- ItemUpdating

These event receivers work as expected in all cases, APART FROM copying and pasting into explorer view. It's worth noting that the event receivers do fire off when MOVING from explorer view into explorer view!

Has anyone else experienced this? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Someone else with the same problem: http://mqsharepoint.blogspot.com/2007/08/sharepoint-explorer-view-cut-paste.html

Comment: Hm that's interesting, my experience is that CUT paste works, but COPY paste doesn't! What's clear is that the event handlers in Explorer View don't work properly!

Comment: Always the first question: Did you install all of the latest patches / sp?

Answer (score 2):

Workaround:

- Create a SharePoint Designer Workflow, attach it to your Doc Library.
- Make it run when the item is changed or updated
- Give it a simple step with the following Action (no conditions)
- Update field in the Current Item
- Select the "Title" field, set it to "Changed".

You are probably able to capture the events from your .NET logic now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are encountering is one of the most annoying features of SharePoint, for some reason it not only overlooks our metadata requirements but also the events you are trying to capture when using the explorer view or unc path.  I beleive the only workaround for this is to create a WWF workflow.

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking of keeping the drag and drop functionality, and losing the Explorer view, you might want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696923/drag-and-drop-files-into-a-sharepoint-webpart-to-upload-into-doclibrary)..