# Error 70 in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I am trying to upload directly a picture/chart from excel to a Sharepoint group URL. Here is the script:

---

Sub ExportChartJPG()

ActiveChart.Export Filename:="http://sharepoint.ap.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/xxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Pictures/MyChart.jpg", _FilterName:="jpeg"

End Sub

---

Is that possible? If it's not then can you suggest another way of doing it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can only export to a file, not to a URL. So, you could export to a temporary file on disk, and then submit the file to your web server. You would of course need the web server to have the ability to receive files.

Hang on, from the URL, it's a SharePoint server, yes? Presumably a SharePoint document library? In that case, you need to write some code to use one of the following techniques to upload the file:

- [SharePoint Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468469/how-do-you-upload-a-file-to-a-document-library-in-sharepoint)
- WebDAV
- FrontPage Extensions

If you want to do this in VBA, then the MSXML3 library may be useful, since it will let you do HTTP requests.

---

**EDIT**: OK, based on your comments, here's a simple VBScript script to get you started. This opens an Excel workbook at a known location, and exports the first chart sheet.

Save this as "test.vbs" and then double-click on it to run it (having created a suitable Excel file, etc.).

```
Dim oExcel : Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Dim oWorkbook : Set oWorkbook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\test.xls")

Dim oChart : Set oChart = oWorkbook.Charts(1)

oChart.Export "C:\chart.jpg", "JPEG"

oWorkbook.Close False

oExcel.Quit
```

As I said in my comment, VBScript is very much like VBA, but the downside is that there's no strong typing, so you don't get Intellisense, etc. It might be easier to create the script in VBA where you *do* have Intellisense (and a debugger, etc.) and then "port" it to VBScript.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try to figure out how to do it. Anyway, as a follow up question, can I make it automated? I mean, can I automate the exporting of image from an excel file then upload it to a sharepoint library? The scenario is I'll have to create a script that can be run in cmd then the procedure is done. The goal is totally no human intervention. How would I do that? 

(I'm a newbie so I'm sorry if I keep on asking. Hope you could bear with me. Thanks again)

Comment: @perfs: Yes, it can be done, but it's not trivial. You can use VBScript (which is very much like VBA) to start Excel, open the workbook, export the chart, and then do the uploading to SharePoint. And this could be kicked off by a scheduled task or suchlike. I suggest you take it one step at a time (maybe start with just the Export part and forget about SharePoint for now) - and be prepared for there to be lots of steps.

Comment: You can also use a 'hybrid' VBScript/VBA approach. Create a VBA macro in the workbook that does the export and upload. The create a VBScript script to start Excel and invoke the macro.