# How do you add a Document programatically to a List in SharePoint?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am using SharePoint 3.0 and I have an XML document that I am using in my application and I want to keep a history of the document so naturally I want to use a SharePoint Document List.  How do I add the document diagrammatically to a List?  Also Can I set permissions on it so that only admins can view/edit the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basics are on [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms454491.aspx)

But to upload to a specific list, instead of web.RootFolder you will grab the list with web.Lists["listname"], theres more details about that in [this other link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468469/how-do-you-upload-a-file-to-a-document-library-in-sharepoint).