# Is it possible to map a document library with a network drive's folder? if possible then how?

Tags: .net, sharepoint-2010

Is it possible to map a  document library with a shared drive's folder in SharePoint 2010? if possible then how? If its not than can this be possible by coding? 
Actually I want automatic synchronization between a document library and a folder on shared drive? how can i able to do that. please give me some light on that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want syncing, SharePoint Workspace if your best answer.  If you just want to map a folder, you can create a network drive, good tutorial here: http://www2.imperial.ac.uk/blog/webguide/2010/07/01/mapping-network-drives-to-sharepoint-libraries/

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely go the other way (map a document library as a network drive) but there are other attributes / metadata that SharePoint is going to want to keep track of which would make  this problematic. Additionally, SharePoint doesn't have OOTB methods to ping a drive for changes, at least not that I'm aware of.

What I'd recommend instead is a timer job that runs maybe once a day (or more often if you aren't concerned about server load), looks at the network drive to see if anything's been added or changed over the last day, and then uploads the files either as a new version of a current document or (if it can't find the filename) as a brand new one.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468469/how-do-you-upload-a-file-to-a-document-library-in-sharepoint) should get you started.