# How to upload a document to SharePoint programmatically?

Tags: sharepoint

I want to upload documents from a web portal to SharePoint programmatically. That is, as user uploads a document it should go directly into SharePoint. I am new to SharePoint and am looking for suggestions/ideas on how to achieve above. Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have multiple ways of uploading a document, depending on where you code is running. The steps are practically the same.

### From the Server Object Model

Use this one if you are working in the SharePoint server side (Web Parts, Event Receivers, Application Pages, etc.)

```
// Get the context
var context = SPContext.Current;

// Get the web reference       
var web = context.Web;

// Get the library reference
var docLib = web.Lists.TryGetList("NAME OF THE LIBRARY HERE");    
if (docLib == null)
{
  return;
}

// Add the document. Y asume you have the FileStream somewhere
docLib.RootFolder.Files.Add(docLib.RootFolder.Url + "FILE NAME HERE", someFileStream);
```

### From client side code (C#)

Use this one if you are working from a client application that consumes SharePoint services.

```
// Get the SharePoint context
ClientContext context = new ClientContext("URL OF THE SHAREPOINT SITE"); 

// Open the web
var web = context.Web;

// Create the new file  
var newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("PATH TO YOUR FILE");
newFile.Url = "NAME OF THE NEW FILE";

// Get a reference to the document library
var docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle("NAME OF THE LIBRARY");
var uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);

// Upload the document
context.Load(uploadFile);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

### From JS using the SharePoint web services

Use this one if you want to upload a document from pages without the server roundtrip:

```
// Get the SharePoint current Context
clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

// Get the web reference
spWeb = clientContext.get_web();

// Get the target list
spList = spWeb.get_lists().getByTitle("NAME OF THE LIST HERE");


fileCreateInfo = new SP.FileCreationInformation();

// The title of the document
fileCreateInfo.set_url("my new file.txt");

// You should populate the content after this
fileCreateInfo.set_content(new SP.Base64EncodedByteArray());

// Add the document to the root folder of the list
this.newFile = spList.get_rootFolder().get_files().add(fileCreateInfo);

// Load the query to the context and execute it (successHandler and errorHandler handle result)
clientContext.load(this.newFile);
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
    Function.createDelegate(this, successHandler),
    Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandler)
);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Which of these solutions should be used with Office 365?

Comment: You can use option number 2 and 3, but I would check if the API was updated. Download the SPO SDK from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42038