# How to upload a page to Share Point programmatically?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I do not have S P installed on my computer. So I was hoping to use the WebServices to do that . I was not able to find any good articles about this . Is there any way to do this using c# ?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload a page just like any other file to a SharePoint document library with the Page content type.

Check this similar post for code in C#:

[How to upload a document to SharePoint programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21508773/how-to-upload-a-document-to-sharepoint-programmatically/21511489#21511489)