# How to upload files to sharepoint online document library using c#

Tags: c#, file-upload, sharepoint-online, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I have a requirement to upload files in to sharepoint online document library. I have around 150 folders and with files and subfolders under them. I need to upload all these files with the folder structure to a document library. I did some research regarding this, but i am not able to find the correct solution for this.i am dot net developer and looking for a solution for this.

Can somebody please help me on how to upload the folders and sub-folders to a sharepoint online document library using c#?

Your help is really appreciable as this critical work for us.

Thanks,
Venu

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21508773/how-to-upload-a-document-to-sharepoint-programmatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asked and answered: 
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/171184/upload-a-folder-with-sub-folders-and-files-recursively-with-pure-csom

Here's an example of one that was already written:

```
public class FileHelper
{
    public static void UploadDocument(ClientContext clientContext, string sourceFilePath, string serverRelativeDestinationPath)
    {
    using (var fs = new FileStream(sourceFilePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var fi = new FileInfo(sourceFilePath);
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, serverRelativeDestinationPath , fs, true);
    }
}

public static void UploadFolder(ClientContext clientContext, System.IO.DirectoryInfo folderInfo, Folder folder)
{
    System.IO.FileInfo[] files = null;
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo[] subDirs = null;

    try
    {
        files = folderInfo.GetFiles("*.*");
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }

    catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }

    if (files != null)
    {
        foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in files)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(fi.FullName);
            clientContext.Load(folder);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            UploadDocument(clientContext, fi.FullName, folder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + fi.Name);
        }

        subDirs = folderInfo.GetDirectories();

        foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo dirInfo in subDirs)
        {
            Folder subFolder = folder.Folders.Add(dirInfo.Name);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            UploadFolder(clientContext, dirInfo, subFolder);
        }
    }
}

public static void UploadFoldersRecursively(ClientContext clientContext, string sourceFolder, string destinationLigraryTitle)
{
    Web web = clientContext.Web;
    var query = clientContext.LoadQuery(web.Lists.Where(p => p.Title == destinationLigraryTitle));
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    List documentsLibrary = query.FirstOrDefault();
    var folder = documentsLibrary.RootFolder;
    System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(sourceFolder);

    clientContext.Load(documentsLibrary.RootFolder);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    folder = documentsLibrary.RootFolder.Folders.Add(di.Name);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    FileHelper.UploadFolder(clientContext, di, folder);
}
}
```

To use it

```
FileHelper.UploadFoldersRecursively(clientContext, @"C:\BigFolder", "Documents");
```