# Upload files to specific document library based on the file content, using visual web part

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I want to upload a document and have to find the keywords in it, Because based on the keyword the document should be uploaded to the respective folders.

For example:

If user uploads a document, My code should read the content and

- If the content is based on the Computer it should upload to CS document library
- else If the content is based on the Biotech it should be uploaded to BT document
  library.

Please help me to do it using visual webpart.

Comment: Do you know how to code anything?  If so please attempt to code the solution and once you get stuck, come and ask a specific question... we have no idea which part you need help on?  Saving documents to a list?  Scanning a word document?  Creating a webpart?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I can understand you need to upload files to specific document library based on the keyword.

Refer this answer, to upload document to doc lib: https://stackoverflow.com/a/468685/1140104

If you want a complete sample, here you go: http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.sg/2012/01/creating-and-deploying-visual-web-part.html#.Uyj_i4U9V3A

In your code,you just need to *change the document library name, based on the keyword*.