# Upload a document to a SharePoint document library (can be via Rest Api/other) using C# & also retrieve the unique id of the document

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need to upload a document to a SharePoint document library (can be via Rest Api/other) using C#.net & also retrieve the unique id/location of the document currently uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468469/how-do-you-upload-a-file-to-a-document-library-in-sharepoint) you can get the information of the uploaded file after `myLibrary.Update()`

Comment: Great help! I would prefer "Upload using Object Model"  from the reference pointed above, but my major concern is to get the document id of the document uploaded currently & how will my application authenticate using the same method? Also can you pls share your mail id in order to connect with you.?