# How can I get File.Delete() to actually delete my file?

Tags: c#, file, sharepoint-2010, delete-file

I generate a PDF file, save it on the server:

```
var bytes = ms.ToArray();
. . .
String fileFullpath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory), pdfFileName);
. . .
File.WriteAllBytes(fileFullpath, bytes);
```

...and then save it into a Sharepoint Document Library, and send it as an email attachment to the person who generated the file:

```
SavePDFToDocumentLibrary(fileFullpath);
String from = GetFromEmailID();
String to = GetUserEmail();
String subjLine = String.Format("The PDF file you generated ({0})", pdfFileName);
String body = String.Format("The Direct Pay PDF file you generated ({0}) is attached.", pdfFileName);
SendEmailWithAttachment(fileFullpath, from, to, subjLine, body);
// Now that it has been put in a Document Library and emailed, delete the file that was saved locally
File.Delete(fileFullpath);
```

...at which point, I no longer need the file I saved to disk on the server, and so, as shown in the last line above, attempt to delete it.

However, it doesn't work. The now-redundant file is still in the place where it was saved.

Why, and how can I get it to understand that "Delete" really means "delete"?

### UPDATE

Here are the methods Scott wanted to see:

```
// This works; got it from Henry Zucchini's answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468469/how-do-you-upload-a-file-to-a-document-library-in-sharepoint
private void SavePDFToDocumentLibrary(String fullpath)
{
    String fileToUpload = fullpath;
    String sharePointSite = siteUrl;
    String documentLibraryName = "DirectPayPDFForms";

    using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(sharePointSite))
    {
        using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
        {
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(fileToUpload))
                throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found.", fileToUpload);

            SPFolder doclib = oWeb.Folders[documentLibraryName];

            // Prepare to upload
            Boolean replaceExistingFiles = true;
            String fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileToUpload);
            FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileToUpload);

            // Upload document
            SPFile spfile = doclib.Files.Add(fileName, fileStream, replaceExistingFiles);

            // Commit 
            doclib.Update();
        }
    }
}

// This is adapted from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage(v=vs.90).aspx
public static void SendEmailWithAttachment(string fileToMail, String from, String to, String subj, String body)
{
    String server = GetSMTPHostName(); //"468802-DEV-SPWF"; // change this to prod when go live, or programatically assign?
    // Specify the file to be attached and sent. 
    string file = fileToMail;
    // Create a message and set up the recipients.
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage(
       from,
       to,
       subj,
       body);

    // Create  the file attachment for this e-mail message.
    Attachment data = new Attachment(file, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
    // Add time stamp information for the file.
    ContentDisposition disposition = data.ContentDisposition;
    disposition.CreationDate = System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(file);
    disposition.ModificationDate = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(file);
    disposition.ReadDate = System.IO.File.GetLastAccessTime(file);
    // Add the file attachment to this e-mail message.
    message.Attachments.Add(data);

    //Send the message.
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(server);
    // Add credentials if the SMTP server requires them.
    client.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

    try
    {
        client.Send(message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in CreateMessageWithAttachment(): {0}", ex.ToString());
    }
    // Display the values in the ContentDisposition for the attachment.
    // May not need/want this section
    ContentDisposition cd = data.ContentDisposition;
    Console.WriteLine("Content disposition");
    Console.WriteLine(cd.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("File {0}", cd.FileName);
    Console.WriteLine("Size {0}", cd.Size);
    Console.WriteLine("Creation {0}", cd.CreationDate);
    Console.WriteLine("Modification {0}", cd.ModificationDate);
    Console.WriteLine("Read {0}", cd.ReadDate);
    Console.WriteLine("Inline {0}", cd.Inline);
    Console.WriteLine("Parameters: {0}", cd.Parameters.Count);
    foreach (DictionaryEntry d in cd.Parameters)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", d.Key, d.Value);
    }
    // </ May not need/want this section
    data.Dispose();
}
```

### UPDATE 2

I see when stepping through it, after adding this test:

```
if (File.Exists(fileFullpath))
{
    File.Delete(fileFullpath);
}
```

...that there *is* an exception after all, in the IOException catch block:

*The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\TEMP.SP.018\Desktop\DirectPayDynamic_2015Jul28_19_02_clayshan_0.pdf' because it is being used by another process.*

So how is one of the other methods holding onto it? ISTM that SavePDFToDocumentLibrary() is safe, because it uses using blocks.

Is data.Dispose(); in SendEmailWithAttachment() not enough? Do I need to explicitly call close there, or what?

### UPDATE 3

I added "message.Dispose();" just prior to "data.Dispose();" in SendEmailWithAttachment(), but it made no difference.

Comment: You have a error either in `SavePDFToDocumentLibrary` or `SendEmailWithAttachment` which is not closing the file. You need to show the code for those two methods. Specificly the place you open a file using `fileFullpath`

Comment: @Mark: No error; it works fine, except for that one issue. Please see my Update with the two methods Scott requested.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.delete(v=vs.110).aspx) it doesn't throw exception if the file doesn't exist. Put a File.Exists() check before the file is deleted just to see if it by any strange reason isn't there.

Comment: Aha! So there is an exception (as I see while stepping through it). Please see Update 2

Comment: You might want to dispose the `SmtpClient` and `MailMessage` as well (implicitly via `using` statement)

Comment: @Christian: SmtpClient doesn't seem to be a candidate for that; I tried it, and got 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'

Comment: I've had this before and had to resort to a retry/sleep scenario - somehow the filesystem didn't immediately release the lock. If you didn't want to take the hit right them, you could create the files in a specific folder and delete all files in that folder that are over a minute old... both are ugly hacks when you code is just as it should work.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon What about `using` the `File.OpenRead` in `SavePDFToDocumentLibrary`?

Comment: @Christian: That did the trick; make it an answer, and I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disposing the file stream used in `SavePDFToDocumentLibrary` like so:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead(fileToUpload))
{
    ...
}
```