# How to use SPSite and SPFile in order to upload/download files from a SharePoint site

Tags: c#, sharepoint, download, upload

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468469/how-do-you-upload-a-file-to-a-document-library-in-sharepoint) answer I have known how to upload/download a file to a sharepoint file.
I have added the nuget package with

> Install-Package Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM -Version 16.1.20616.12000

with

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
```

The problem is that I don't know how to reference  SPSite and SPFile because I can't find it in any namespace.

[image]

The

Thanks

Comment: @Clemens so is it not relevant WPF? I have seen differences in that context between WPF and WF but I am new to sharepoint and I might be wrong.

Comment: The question does not seem to have anything to do with WPF.

Comment: SPSite is not a part of Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM. It's from C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.dll as mentioned in the comment under accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks. But I had disregarded that because under C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared I have no "Web server extension" folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly install the nuget package with

Install-Package Microsoft.SharePoint.dll

info is [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePoint.dll/)

Comment: It works thanks. But I still have an error on the var type Folder.

Comment: It is SPFolder not folder!

Comment: I believe that for WPF it better is following this example https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4baa9152-8e11-410f-934a-78d9119f970f/c-wpf-how-to-download-and-upload-file-from-sharepoint-teamsite-document-library?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Comment: Otherwise you will have problems in linking and embedding the dlls.