# Saving a PDF file to Sharepoint using .NET

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, aspose.words

I need some advice actually.
I'm working on Aspose Words .NET and using that I created a PDF to my local system without any problem.

Here is the code I used to save the pdf doc:

```
doc.Save(savePath+"Myfile.pdf");
```

Now I want to save that pdf file directly to a Sharepoint folder using .Net, What should I do ? I have Sharepoint folder path, Username and Password as well, but couldn't find a right way to do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you upload a file to a document library in sharepoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468469/how-do-you-upload-a-file-to-a-document-library-in-sharepoint)

Comment: thanks for your quick reply @MindSwipe , but I'm asking that I don't want to use the local system, can we directly use aspose to save the pdf doc in sharepoint folder?

Comment: You can save your aspose document to a `MemoryStream` and then use that stream to upload it to a sharepoint location. Be aware that that will use a lot of memory (a little more than the entire size of the document), so you should really only this with relatively small documents

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to save document in a Sharepoint folder using Aspose.Words. To achieve this you should first [save your document to a stream](https://docs.aspose.com/words/net/save-a-document/#save-a-document-to-a-stream) using Aspose.Words and then upload the resulting document in Sharepoint.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer , but can you please provide some code snippet to upload the `MemoryStream` document in Sharepoint?

Comment: You can use the approach suggested by @MindSwipe. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468469/how-do-you-upload-a-file-to-a-document-library-in-sharepoint Also here is another example https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/bc27a541-2ea3-4506-88a3-75dee4027f7d/how-to-upload-files-from-c-aspnet-to-sharepoint-online-library?forum=onlineservicessharepoint